# Issue in running Eclipse

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu, java, eclipse, openjdk

Linux noob here.
My pc runs lubuntu 18.04.4 lts(32-bit)
I have installed jdk11 by typing `sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jre`
I just installed eclipse from the software center and opened it.
[image: Eclipse error at launch] and this occured.
When I opened the log file, it said :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2020-06-24 18:29:40.331
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I have no idea what all these mean. Could anyone help me out?

```
apt-cache policy eclipse
```

The above command says that I have not installed Eclipse. But Software center shows the launch button.
Sorry if I'm not able to provide the required info to you.
Warm greetings.

Comment: Which version of eclipse have you installed and how? Did you use `umake` or downloaded a tarball?

Comment: That is Eclipse 3.8.1 which is now 8 years and 14 releases old. It will not run with Java 11 - Java 8 would be the last release it will run on.